Nested Field in Logstash OpenSearch are not coming through as array's
I'm losing my mind over here and OpenSearch's documentation is completely unhelpful as everything is hardcoded values.
Anyways, I have a nested field that is supposed to be flattened into an array but it's not working so I'm obviously missing something (ignore the goofy naming of the field; it's so we don't have to make drastic changes to a plugin we're currently using)
Index is created with this command:
curl -XPUT -u "$OPENSEARCH_USER:$OPENSEARCH_PASSWORD" $OPENSEARCH_HOST_URL/mechanism-search -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @/tmp/mechanism-search-index.json

mechanism-search-index.json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "mechanism": {
        "properties": {
          "mechanism_id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "mechanism_name": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      },
      "projects": {
        "type" : "nested",
        "include_in_parent": "true",
        "properties": {
          "project_id__type_list": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "project_name__type_list": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

The Projects should be nested fields of the Mechanism so I'd expect something like this to be returned with GET mechanism-search/_search:
"mechanism_id" : "1111",
"mechanism_name" : "Test Mech",
"projects" : [
   {
     "project_id__type_list" : 1,
     "project_name__type_list" : "testing1"
   },
   {
     "project_id__type_list" : 2,
     "project_name__type_list" : "testing2"
   },
   {
     "project_id__type_list" : 3,
     "project_name__type_list" : "testing3"
   },
   {
     "project_id__type_list" : 4,
     "project_name__type_list" : "testing4"
   }
 ]

Instead I get:
"mechanism_id" : "1111",
"mechanism_name" : "Test Mech",
"project_id__type_list" : 1,
"project_name__type_list" : "testing1"

The field names in the mapping and the DB view match exactly. Why is it only grabbing a single Project for the Mechanism when there are multiple rows in the DB? Opensearch's Documentation is all using PUTS and hardcoded values directly to a document; how am I supposed to make this automatic? I'm coming from SOLR and none of this is making any sense and seems massively overly complicated.
Mechanism's and Projects are joined via a cross-table and the DB view OpenSearch uses points to it with a join.
Sample DB View Data:


When you say "so I'd expect something like this to be returned:" where do you expect it and how do you get what you got instead?

that's what I'd expect it to return with GET mechanism-search/_search. Added info to the post for clarification

It would be helpful to see how you create these records. A complete example would be really helpful here. By a complete example I mean an example that consists of 3 complete commands that somebody could run locally: 1) this is how I create an index 2) this is how I add the records 3) this is how I search and get unexpected result

AFAIK, OpenSearch Auto-magically creates them from the database view it's pointed to. The mapping is just for explicitly defining column types and whatnot.
curl -XPUT -u "$OPENSEARCH_USER:$OPENSEARCH_PASSWORD" $OPENSEARCH_HOST_URL/mechanism-search -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @/tmp/mechanism-search-index.json

Indeed "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic". I am afraid we would need to take a look at record creation to answer your question. BTW, does that mapping change after you populate the index with records? Can you post the output of curl -XGET -u "$OPENSEARCH_USER:$OPENSEARCH_PASSWORD" $OPENSEARCH_HOST_URL/mechanism-search after the records has been added?

That curl command is what populates the OpenSearch database using the mapping; it is the creation of the record. But it's not creating the nested records as arrays as it should. What you see in the "Instead I get" is what it creates the index with and it's wrong.

Sorry, "and it's wrong" is not enough information for me to be able to help you. I need to see the records that you add to the index, how addition of these records modify the mapping and what you get as the result of search. Good luck!

What you see in the "instead I get" are the records. There is not munging or manipulating of data going on; it's raw. OpenSearch is supposed to understand it's a Nested Field (via the mapping) and make it an array but it's not.

OpenSearch is not using mapping to manipulate or reformat the data that you send to it. It is only used to know how to index that data. You get back what you sent to OpenSearch. If what you send is improperly formatted with project_id__type_list as the top element OpenSearch will not auto-magically stick into an array under project no matter what mapping you specify. There is no magic there.

Correct. But it seems to randomly grab 1 item from the what would be in the array and shoves it in as a string and ignores the others. One time it'll be testing1 that gets thrown in and upon recreation it'll randomly grab a different one (like testing3). Does OS not handle multiple rows in the DB from a join? Or is it expecting it to be a separate JSON object? From my mapping and what I'm seeing in docs and online I should have everything that is needed.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

So, the problem is not in OpenSearch here, the problem is in the upstream system (logstash in this case) that generates one record per project instead of one record per mechanism. I suspect that records have the same id so only one project record per mechanism survives.
To combine multiple project records together you can use aggregate filter.
